# What to do when an algorithm question attracts "Here's my implementation in X" answers?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

So I was looking through the close review queue today and I saw this question: [An algorithm for finding converse duplicates of ordered pairs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246616/an-algorithm-for-finding-converse-duplicates-of-ordered-pairs)

The OP asked for an algorithm to find certain parts of related elements in a list. For some reason, all the answers are of the form "Here's my solution in [language]: [big block of code]" without any attempt at discussing algorithmic trade-offs like worst-case time complexity versus implementation complexity. I would assume the latter is what we want from an "algorithm question"; otherwise they should Google or ask on SO with a specific language tag (right?).

My first question is: **What should we do when this happens to a question?** Closing doesn't feel right to me, since it's still a well-written, on-topic, answerable question. It has been protected, which I completely agree with, but there's probably something else that should be done.

---

For the record, I was prompted to ask this because of the somewhat odd custom close reason that was provided. See these comments:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as written and
>   answered, the question is answerable by unexplained code snippets in
>   arbitrary languages. –  MichaelT 2 days ago
>
> @MichaelT: Full marks for originality: I've never seen that as a close
>   reason before. It was a serious question about an actual problem and I
>   was disappointed at the outcome. I thought it deserved better answers,
>   but is that the fault of the question? –  david.pfx yesterday
>
> @david.pfx I'm not sure. I remember looking at the question nearly a
>   year ago and thinking it looked good and could get some good answers.
>   Unfortunately, what you are getting is "here's an implementation in
>   python, here's another one in ruby..." and it appears to be taking on
>   more of an algorithm golf problem nature (with some code) than what
>   I'd really like to see from the question. –  MichaelT yesterday

My second question is what the OP asked here: **Was this the fault of the question?** or better yet **Could the question be edited in a way that might discourage these "code-only" answers?**

I'm also not sure if this is a trend or just one exceptionally unlucky question; I personally haven't seen it happen anywhere else, but I haven't searched for more examples.

Comment: Programmers is [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are [expected to _explain_ things](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there are two things that need to be addressed.

### The Question

When I see a question that has a good idea but poor phrasing, I will edit it to be more objective and to ask for a more abstract, conceptual answer. In that question, *what is the algorithm*?

The difficult part is that specific question already asks for an algorithm, then goes on to request a solution in actual code. In other words, it is saying "here is my problem, write my code for me." To the author's credit, he did a really good job describing the problem, explained his mental block, and gave objective success criteria. For those reasons, I would not vote to close the question, I would improve it.

I did [edit that question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/246616/revisions) to remove the code request.

### The Answers

This is one is easy. Answers of poor quality should be downvoted.

When a question does not already have a quality answer worthy of being accepted, feel free to provide one even if it is an old question.

Comment: Somehow I completely missed the part of the question that was asking for code. That explains a lot, thanks.